# Conditional presence of attributes based on other attribute values

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML that needs to go through a pretty rigid validation using a schema.
Problem is that some of the attributes on some of the elements are only required when a "type" attribute has certain value(s).

For example:

```
<someElement type="foo" att1="bla" />
<someElement type="bar" att1="blu" />
```

In my case, for `type="foo"` should validate fine, but for `type="bar"` it shouldn't because for "bar" another attribute `att2` must be present.

Is this sort of thing even possible using a schema, or do I need to declare a new complexType instead of `<someElement>` that will only allow what I need?

I tried the "similar questions" section but couldn't find something that addresses this issue specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described is pretty much an exact match to the "conditional type assignment" mechanism in XSD 1.1 (where the value of one attribute is used to decide which of several types to validate against).

There's no way of doing this in XSD 1.0.

Comment: Is there an example of how that is implemented somewhere? I tried reading the XSD specs and it made me cry.

Comment: There are a few introductory tutorials around, e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml11pt2/. Sorry I misled your search engine by getting the name wrong: it is "conditional type assignment". (Editing to correct it).

Comment: If it's any consolation, I think the XSD spec is the most difficult thing I have read since the Algol 68 report; with the notable difference that the formalisms in Algol 68 actually work, whereas even when you've mastered the XSD spec, you find many of your questions unanswered.